# Setting a default value in a blank field in an Access query

Tags: ms-access, default-value

This may have been answered elsewhere, but I can't find it!

I'm combining 2 queries from different sources onto a single query for calculation and reporting purposes.  Fields which are not common to both sources show as blank if there is no data, and can't then be used in arithmetic.

I want to set a default of zero where blank, instead of having to knife and fork the query into another table and run an update query over all the blank fields.

There's got to be something simpler!  HELP!

Comment: An iif() or Nz() should do the trick, but could you please edit your question to include your query?

Comment: @JohnK813 I think you may as well post this as an answer :)

Comment: Do you want to change your table structure so the fields have default values, or do you want to update the existing data to get rid of all the Nulls, or do you just want to convert them to some value in your data retrieval or presentation layer? Do you need the Nulls? Are the meaningful, or would 0 (or some other appropriate default value) be more useful?

Comment: I Used Nz function to put Zero in empty fileds but when i tried to perform calculation for them, they combine together like the pictuer below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZfNL.png)

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
nz(value1, 0), nz(value2,0), nz(value3,0)
FROM table1 left outer join table2 on table1.column = table2.column
```

unless your query resembles what John answered with (a cartesian) then his answer is more appropriate.... (cartesians are dangerous if not used correctly... depending on how big the individual tables are allowed to become you can kill an access application by using them)

Answer (score 0):

You'll either want to use [Nz()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx) or [iif()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx), depending on whether that "blank" really is just a blank (empty string) or Null.

So your options are:

```
SELECT Nz(source1.a + source2.b,0) FROM source1, source2
```

or:

```
SELECT iif(source1.a + source2.b <> "", source1.a + source2.b, 0) FROM source1, source2
```

Comment: I am afraid you must use Nz about each field (column) or null will be returned if one of the fields are null.

Comment: just to expand on your example a little bit.... you could do 'nz(source1.a) as val1, nz(source2.b,0) as val2, val1 + val2 as total'  with all the appropriate brackets of course